# How Fermi momentum and Fermi energy are related?

Tags: electrons, fermions, electronic-band-theory, spin-statistics

The Fermi momentum is defined as $\sqrt{2mE_F}$, where $E_F$ is the Fermi energy. Does this equation mean that the Fermi momentum depends only on the kinetic part of the Fermi energy?

Is it correct to say that turning on an external field for a spin-half system affects only the Fermi energy and not the Fermi momentum?

Answer (score 2):

The energy and momentum are related by the "dispersion relation." For a classical free particle, the kinetic energy of a particle is the total energy and so

$$ E=\frac{p^2}{2m} \rightarrow p = \sqrt{2mE}.$$

That is the origin of the relation you mentioned. For a relativistic free particle, you have the Einstein dispersion

$$ E^2 = p^2 + m^2,$$

and you would get a different relationship between the energy and momentum. So in general, translating from the fermi momentum to the fermi energy requires knowledge of the dispersion.

So the answer is yes, the Fermi energy to Fermi momentum translation is different for a free particle and one which is in some potential.

Answer (score 0):

Depends in what setting, but I think Fermi energy is a terrible term. The best way to think of it is that is it just the chemical potential at $T=0$. Although, some books have a slightly different definition/terminology. Sometimes its not completely consist from book to book.